# Combinations of colored cubes

Tags: probability

Given three cubes and three colors (say red, green, and blue) I would like to calculate how many different ways I may associate colors with the cubes, not counting options like BGG and GBG twice. I have enumerated all the possibilities, I found it to be 10. I was wondering if there was a more general way to calculate it, if, I say, had x cubes and y colors.

Comment: Think of the formula for combination with repitition.

Answer (score 1):

For small numbers like yours, any reasonably systematic method of listing and counting is a good way to handle the problem. So the answer below is useful mainly for larger numbers of cubes and/or colours.

Think of the colours of paint as distinct *bins*, and of the cubes as identical *balls*. Choosing a colour scheme is equivalent to placing balls in bins. For example, the colour scheme BBG means placing $2$ balls in the Blue bin and $1$ in the Green bin.

There is a standard method, often called [Stars and Bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars,) for solving such problems. If we have $x$ cubes, and $y$ colours of paint, that is, $x$ identical balls and $y$ distinct bins, then there are
$$\binom{x+y-1}{x},\quad\text{or equivalently}\quad \binom{x+y-1}{y-1}\tag{1}$$
to place the balls in the bins.

For your case $x=y=3$, this gives $\binom{5}{3}$, that is, $10$ ways.

We will not write out a justification of Formula 1, since the Wikipedia article linked to above is quite good. In addition, there are many many questions and answers on MSE that use Stars and Bars.

Comment: Wouldn't the bottom number there be 2 and not 3 if p=3?

Comment: I used the $\binom{x+y-1}{x}$ version of Formula (1), which gives $\binom{5}{3}$. The other version gives $\binom{5}{2}$. These binomial coefficients are the same, both equal to $10$.

Comment: Okay, using the (x+y-1) x formula, I can see where you got 5 and 3; however, I'm still not grasping how exactly you got the 10 from that. 

5!/3! = 20, not 10? Where does the additional 2 come in?

Comment: The binomial coefficient $\binom{n}{k}$ is equal to $\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$. So $\binom{5}{3}=\frac{5!}{3!2!}=10$.

Comment: Okay, I've plugged in the numbers and gotten that particular problem to work; so just to drive the point home let us change the circumstances.

What if n=8 and k=6? So we begin with (8+6-1) gives us 13 and 8. That gives us 13!/8!5! = 1287 possible individual outcomes??

Comment: I do not know what your $n$ and $k$ refer to. I can answer your question if you tell me the number of cubes and the number of colours.